# PowerApps gallery to form, how do i disable SAVE button when Form is in view mode?

Tags: sharepoint-online, save, powerapps-forms, button

I am not a coder, but trying to understand the logic and write the correct formula in PowerApps.

When I select 'Edit' from my 'Gallery1', it opens my 'BuildForm' screen in Power Apps.
I want the SAVE button on my 'BuildForm' screen to DISABLE when viewing the form.

Right now I have my SAVE button **DisplayMode** control set to:

`If(BuildForm.Valid,DisplayMode.Edit, DisplayMode.Disabled)`

It is disabled until the form is fully completed by the user.

How do I tell it to also disable the SAVE button when someone is only Viewing the information in the BuildForm?

Comment: How do you differentiate if user is viewing the form or editing the form? Do you have separate buttons (view & edit) in gallery to navigate to same screen? Did you set the form mode to edit or based on any conditions?

Comment: @GaneshSanap User is viewing the form. From the gallery, yes, i have two separate buttons for view and edit. The DEFAULT control on the form is set to 'Edit'. Is that something I need to update?

Comment: Yes, when you click on "View" button from gallery, set `FormMode`/`Mode` of form control to `FormMode.View` & when clicking on "Edit" button, set `FormMode`/`Mode` of form control to `FormMode.Edit`. Check [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-form) for more information on Form modes.

Comment: Ganesh, this is what I have ONSELECT:  **Navigate(BuildForm, ScreenTransition.Fade); ViewForm(BuildForm)**

Comment: Ok, then try my below suggestions & let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the button property based on form mode then you can use the `FormMode`.

Example:

```
If(BuildForm.Valid || BuildForm.Mode = FormMode.Edit,DisplayMode.Edit, DisplayMode.Disabled)
```

OR

```
If(BuildForm.Valid || BuildForm.Mode = FormMode.Edit || BuildForm.Mode = FormMode.New,DisplayMode.Edit, DisplayMode.Disabled)
```

You can add/remove conditions in above formula as per your requirements.